# How to set the text in an Adapter, in Android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, adapter

I have no idea how to set a text to a `TextView` in a `getView()` method. If I leave it there, it will cause a `NullPointerException`. I have tried with a log and it is printed many times.

PS: Obviously, I'm sure that the variable contains a valid string.

```
public class DayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    private Context mContext;
    private Day[] mDays;
    private String mCity;
    private String mAdminArea;

    public DayAdapter(Context context, Day[] days, String city, String adminArea) {
        mContext = context;
        mDays = days;
        mCity = city;
        mAdminArea = adminArea;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDays.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mDays[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0; // we aren't going to use this. Tag items for easy reference
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.daily_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.iconImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
            holder.temperatureLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temperatureLabel);
            holder.dayLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayNameLabel);
            holder.locationLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.locationLabel);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Day day = mDays[position];

        holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(day.getIconId());

        holder.temperatureLabel.setText(day.getTemperatureMax() + "");

        Log.d(DayAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), mCity); // this is called many times 

        holder.locationLabel.setText(mCity); // this cause the error





        if (position == 0) {
            holder.dayLabel.setText("Today");
        }
        else {
            holder.dayLabel.setText(day.getDayOfTheWeek());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView iconImageView; // public by default
        TextView temperatureLabel;
        TextView dayLabel;
        TextView locationLabel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you double-check if there is really a view with id `locationLabel` in layout `daily_list_item`?

Comment: Instead of `mContext = Context` in the constructor, do `this.mContext = Context`

Comment: When you log the city, it gets printed right? If the city is printed then it means your text view is null. Check your ids so you actually get a text view from the xml layout.

Comment: @AmanGrover that makes no difference at all ...

Comment: Oh, I did a terrible mistake. I tried to set the textview that belong to another activity. Thanks guys.